# Loop over objects with similar names

Tags: c++, string, pointers, object, for-loop

I have a set of common objects in c++ named `object1, object2, object3, ...`.
These objects are constructed from a class, that provides some functions, like `Add()` which "merges" two or more objects.

What I want to do is loop over the object and merge them all together. If I use

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 30 ; i++){

    TString::Format("object%d",i)->Add();

}
```

obviously it cannot work, because I am trying to access an object using a wrong pointer to call it.

First of all, I would like to know if there is a way to loop over the objects and secondly if there is a specific name for this procedure.

**EDIT** I thought of using an `array` or a `vector` and access it from there, but in order to fill the array I have to give many `push_back` commands, which is not convenient if you have `100` objects.

Comment: make an array or other list of whatever type your objects are and iterate over that

Comment: How about creating an array (`some_type object[30]`) instead? Then you can index it from `object[0]` through `object[29]`. (`for (size_t i = 0; i < 30; ++i) { object[i].Add(); }`)

Comment: You should get an idea when to use arrays

Comment: But how am I going to fill the vector if I have, let's say, 100 objects but still with a similar name?

Comment: @Thanos I don't understand your question. I'm proposing that you *don't even have* these object*N* variables and instead store your objects directly in some kind of array or vector.

Comment: I could do that, provided that I am the one who creates the objects, which is not the case...

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, because variable names are compile-time artifacts in C++. Apart from the debugger which gets additional information "on the side", a program cannot access a variable by its name.

If you need to associate an object with a name or an index, put the desired objects in a container. If you need access by name, use `map<string,YourObjectType>` or `unordered_map<string,YourObjectType>`. If you need access by index, use `vector<YourObjectType>`:

```
vector<YourObjectType*> objectPtrs;
objectPtrs.push_back(&object0);
objectPtrs.push_back(&object1);
objectPtrs.push_back(&object2);
...
objectPtrs.push_back(&object29);
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 30 ; i++){
    TString::Format(*objectPtrs[i])->Add();
}
```

The example above makes a container of pointers so that the loop accesses the original objects, not their copies stored in a vector. You could eliminate the original object variables by storing them in a vector, and accessing them by index rather than by name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I thought of using `array` or `vector` but I have to fill it manually with objects that have the similar name. If for instance there are 100 or maybe 1000 objects, it's not very convenient to fill an array by hand.

Comment: @Thanos If you have 100+ similarly named variables that you access individually by name, then there's something wrong with your design: they should go into a collection to start with, rather than being individual variables.

Comment: I have a file created by root(http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) which contains a lot of histograms(`TH1F` class) so the desing  is waht it is and unfortunately don't have access to the creation...

Comment: @Thanos Ah, OK, writing manual code against automatically generated files is a problem. I do not know anything about root.cern's work, but if you need to deal with it, you could use a pointer approach described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code which creates the objects in the first place:

Build-up a key-value pair, during their creation/construction and enter them into a map.

The key is going to be "Object1", "Object2" etc. Value will be the pointer to the object allocated/created just now.

Push these pairs into a map.

When it is time to iterate over a set of objects, recreate that name ("ObjectN") and lookup in the map, to get back the pointer to the object.

```
[
  ["Object2", ptr-to-Object2]
  ["Object7", ptr-to-Object7]
  ...
]
```

This won't assume anything about the indices etc. You build a name-to-object association and look it up when you iterate.

Comment: Wow!!! That is a very nice suggestion! Unfortunately I don't have access to the source code, althougth if I did, I don't know exactly how to set this up...